# Junit: How to stubs the following java class in junit

Tags: junit

Hi I have a class which the invoke the run() method of a thread from the constructor of the class by calling the start() method , So please help me to Stubs the so to write the junit test cases . The class is as follows

> public class MyClass extends Thread  {
>        Student st=null;
>          University uni= new University();
>
> ```
>  public MyClass(Student st)    {
>      this.st=st;
>      start();
>  }
>  public void run()     {
>     uni.calculate(st);
>  }
>   }
> ```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to test `Student`, call Student#calculate directly from your test. There does not seem to be anything test-worthy in `MyClass`.

Comment: i want to call the calculate method of University class in the run method

Comment: Your question is a sign that calling `start()` from the constructor might be something you want to reconsider! ;)

Comment: Yes i want consider that. and how can i stub the run method in junit test class

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the discussion here:

[Testing Constructor With Powermock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409153/testing-constructors-with-powermock/12409928#comment16750083_12409928)

It discusses sub-classing and overriding.

In general it should be considered bad practice to have to mock the class under test in order to test it. It is also hard to do since most mocking frameworks will not allow mocking a single method once in the class under test since they create wrapping proxies.